# Visual Studio C# Office2007 Form Style not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, office-2007

I'm using DotNetBar in VS for C#, and when I change the form to office2007, the design preview looks right, but then when I run the program, the style changes back to the default winform style.

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Wild guess: there's a line of code in your application (say, the constructor?) that changes the style to the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running on Windows that has Glass then you need to set EnableGlass=false

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!! :D :D :D :D :D. Saved me. I spent every waking hour yesterday trying to figure this out. It's still not working properly with the office2007ribbonform, but knowing this problem was that simple, I'll just mess with the settings. Thanks so much man. Also, is there any way I can contact you in case I have an easy problem like this?

Comment: Oh, you're THE devcomponents guy. I don't suppose you'd want to offer support like I asked, but as for the other problem, the menu bar not showing up, do you know anything about it.